# Access properties of knockout observable

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a knockout observable: **self.productBarcode = ko.observable()**, and I use jquery autocomplete to search in a list of products, if the products are found I have a select event in the autocomplete function to add the object selected to the observable:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
                updateElementValueWithLabel(event, ui);
                self.productBarcode(ui);
```

The **ui** object has the following format:

```
ui
{ 
    item 
    { 
       barcode: "2"
       label: "p1"
       value: "p1"
    }
}
```

Then what I need is to select the product **barcode** from the **productBarcode** which have the same format as ui.

**Problem**: How can I access the barcode property from the observable **productBarcode**?
I've tried the folowing:

```
    self.addNewSale = function() {
    var placeNewSale = {
        StoreId: self.SaleStoreObject().Id,
        StoreName: self.SaleStoreObject().Name,
        ProductBarcode: self.productBarcode().barcode,
        ProductName: self.productBarcode().label,
        Quantity: self.newSale.Quantity()
    }

    self.placeSaleProducts().push(placeNewSale);
    self.placeSaleProducts(self.placeSaleProducts());
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking... What is the expected behavior and what's the outcome of your current code? (Also, note that you can push to an `observableArray` directly by omitting the `()` before `.push`)

Comment: I'm trying to access the barcode property from an object which have the format of the **ui**

Comment: Like `obj.item.barcode`?

Comment: I cannot access directly with something like: **self.productBarcode().barcode** because I get that this is **undefined**

Comment: Yes, somethig like obj.item.barcode

Comment: If the observable's value can be (or is initially) undefined, you'll need to include a check for that. e.g.: `if (typeof self.productBarcode() !== "undefined")`

Comment: @user3297291: that was what I was looking for, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a `ko.observable` like so:

```
self.productBarcode = ko.observable();
```

its initial value will be `undefined`. This means you cannot blindly access its properties by doing something like:

```
var currentBarcode = self.productBarcode().item.barcode;
```

This would result in javascript trying to access the `item` property of `undefined`, which it can't...

You could check for `undefined`, or go with a shorter but less "safe" falsey-check:

```
// Option 1: Explicitly check for undefined:
var current = self.productBarcode(),
    currentBarcode = (typeof current !== "undefined") ? current.item.barcode : null;
```

```
// Option 2: Check if there's "something truthy" in the observable
var current = self.productBarcode(),
    currentBarcode = current ? current.item.barcode : null;
```